# Soltek SL-52B2 motherboard manual

Tags: ibm-pc, motherboard

I'm looking for the manual of this motherboard. Google can't seem to find one for this exact model, only similar ones. Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Mind to add information about type and chipset and so on? In General it should be similar to [this](https://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=365386), so give it a try.

Comment: The chipset is Intel, but I don't know if it's really important. Motherboard docs are issued for each type, but not variants of a type, with different chipsets, etc. If there are variants, the manual makes note of them.

Comment: @the whole 52 series used the same BIOS, so go and check the manual linked.